# The operation of email bounces message

Tags: email, email-bounces

I would like to know the bounces message is sent from own MTA or others?

e.g.

a sender use gmail MTA to deliver mail, if encounter error (soft/hard bounces) ,

Which MTA will deliver the bounces to sender, gmail one or other side or any intermediate MTA?

I would like to know when the bounces will send to the sender as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bounce messages are sent from/by the MTA that encountered the error (which is not always the one that *generated* the error)

They are just an email message like any other, and they are handled/routed just like every other email on the Internet.

---

Example 1: You send mail to an address that doesnt exist.
When your ISP's mail server contacts the recipients mail server it gets a 5xx "That person doesn't exist" message.  Your ISP's mail server puts a bounce message in your inbox.

---

Example #2: You send mail to an address that doesn't exist. The recipient's mail server is behind a spam filter that accepts your message, scans it & tries to send it on, but gets the same 5xx message as in Example 1. The spam filter generates a bounce message addressed to you and sends it back to your ISP's mail server to be put in your inbox.